# Terminating SimPy simulation

Tags: python, simpy

I am using one of the examples in the tutorial as a basis to model call center simulation.

Simulation is for one hour window (max simulation time of 60 minutes). When I execute `env.run(until = 60)` calls arrive even few seconds before 60 minute ends, which is quite ok and realistic.

I'm trying to have the simulation terminate when the resource served this last call. Is there a way to do this?

Any guidance or advice on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass any event to `env.run(until=event)`.  The simulation will run until this event has been triggered.

`env.run(until=60)` is just a shortcut for `env.run(until=env.timeout(60))` (if `env.now == 0`).